# How do I add a domain.com on body of markdown without turning it into a link?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

So I'm writing a blog and to explain I'm using example.com/ in my essay at a number of places. I don't want them to turn into links. How do I escape?

1. example.com = correct
2. [example.com](http://example.com) != correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a code span by wrapping the URL in backticks:

```
I'm using `example.com/` in my essay at a number of places
```

As per the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-code-element), a `code` element can contain "any... string that a computer would recognize." As a URL is a string that a computer recognizes, then it should be wrapped in a `code` element. The way that is accomplished in Markdown is by wrapping the string in backticks to create a code span. As the [Markdown rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) explain:

> To indicate a span of code, wrap it with backtick quotes (`). Unlike a
>   pre-formatted code block, a code span indicates code within a normal
>   paragraph. For example:
>
> ```
> Use the `printf()` function.
> ```
>
> will produce:
>
> ```
> <p>Use the <code>printf()</code> function.</p>
> ```

And, more importantly for you, anything within a code span is not parsed as Markdown.

This answer wouldn't be complete without mentioning that the original rules do not suggest that plain URLs within text should be given any special treatment. According to the original rules, [automatic links](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autolink) require special markup, namely that the URL be surrounded in angle brackets. Like this: `<http://example.com/>`. As a plain URL without angle brackets in the text would be ignored, there is no specially defined method to escape a URL. In fact, that is how Markdown behaves here in StackOverflow.

However, many users have not liked this behavior and want all their URLs to be autolinks even without wrapping them in angle brackets. Therefore a number a implementations will autolink all URLs. Unfortunately, this means that the only way to escape the autolinking is to wrap the URL in a code span if you are using such an implementation.

Comment: Dang!, why didn't I think of this. Thank you!

Comment: Jekyll appears to be converting encapsulated code into hyperlinks still, for some reason. I raised an issue at [Github](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7222).

Comment: Wow. That definitely seems like a bug to me.